# In QSAR, what is the simplest (but most powerful) way to create an applicability domain model?

Tags: cheminformatics

QSAR means Quantitative Structure Activity Relationship.

An applicability domain model is a model that tells you how far you are from the domain where your model was trained. I.e. it is a kind of map where you can place molecules. And on this map, there is some delimited territory that you have explored while you were training your model.

Let's say I have created a QSAR model on some training dataset, and validated it on a test set.

Next, I'd like to create a model that gives me a 1.0 (or nearby) if the molecule I present to the QSAR model looks similar to the training set, but a 0.0 (or nearby) if it looks dissimilar.

Currently, I was thinking about training a one class Support Vector Machine on the training set.

Broad picture: I'd like to get a warning in case the QSAR model is presented with something that looks too far from anything it was trained on. The warning would mean: "be careful with this prediction".

Comment: Welcome to the site! It might be a good idea to identify the acronyms (QSAR, SVM) you use and elaborate on your question further (what is an applicability domain model?).

Comment: I believe the paper you want look at is: Netzeva, T. I., Worth, A. P., Aldenberg, T., Benigni, R., Cronin, M. T., Gramatica, P., ... & Myatt, G. (2005). Current status of methods for defining the applicability domain of (quantitative) structure-activity relationships. ATLA, 33, 155-173. It describes several different methods of choosing the AD. All of have pros and cons, so you will have to choose the one which best fits your problem.